# Python 3.6 Beautiful Soup - Trouble to Get Embedded Video URL during Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, embedded-video

I am trying to scrape a web page and to retrieve the URL for an embedded video on a web page using Beautiful Soup and requests modules in Python 3.6. When I inspect the HTML on the webpage in Chrome, I can see the .mp4 link of the video. But when I get the page using requests and Beautiful Soup, I can't find the "video" node. I have understood that the video window is a nested HTML document. In particular, I want to scrape this webpage - http://videolectures.net/icml2015_liang_language_understanding/ and get the video link - http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/6f/n5vruqvdwpj36mdoxxwyxvyg5hje7a4c.mp4 using Beautiful Soup and requests modules. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an obfuscated configuration located here :

http://videolectures.net/icml2015_liang_language_understanding/video/1/page.map

This url itself is built from the fields `site_slug` and `video` located in the [original page](http://videolectures.net/icml2015_liang_language_understanding/) harcoded in JS :

```javascript
var viipg = {
    cfg: {
        slug: 'icml2015_liang_language_understanding',
        type: 'Lecture',
        obj_id: 23694,
        video: 1,
        video_id: 23648,
        videos: [1, 2],
        chrome_colors: ["FFFFFF", "F21F1F"],
        livepipe: '//videolectures.net',
        site_slug: 'vln',
        media_url: 'https://static.videolectures.net/r.1483388978/',
        sentry: '//161ef9a5c3a14af1848399909b890522@sentry.viidea.com/6'
    },
    ..........................
};
```

The file is decoded with an algorithm in JS. I've re-arranged the minified code in a [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) script :

```javascript
"use strict"

var b = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~-_.,;:<>!?*+=\"'#$%&/\\()\n\t ";
var c = b.length;

function d(a) {
    var c, d = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < a.length; c += 1){
        d += b.indexOf(a[c]);
    }
    return d >=0 ? d : 0;
}
function e(a, e) {
    var f, g, h = [];
    e = d(e);
    for (var g = 0; g < a.length; g += 1) {
        f = b.indexOf(a[g]);
        if(f > -1){
            var ni = ((f - e - 6 * g) % c + c) % c;
            h.push(b[ni]);
        } else {
            h.push(a[g]);
        }
    }
    return h.join("");
}

var slug = "icml2015_liang_language_understanding";

require('http').get('http://videolectures.net/icml2015_liang_language_understanding/video/1/page.map', (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (body) {
        console.log(e(body.substring(1),slug));
    });
});
```

It works well and decode the file into valid xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<smil>
<head>
    <meta name="title" content="Natural Language Understanding: Foundations and State-of-the-Art" />
    <meta name="abstract" content="Building systems that can understand human language—being able to answer questions, follow instructions, carry on dialogues—has been a long-standing challenge since the early days of AI. Due to recent advances in machine learning, there is again renewed interest in taking on this formidable task. A major question is how one represents and learns the semantics (meaning) of natural language, to which there are only partial answers. The goal of this tutorial is (i) to describe the linguistic and statistical challenges that any system must address; and (ii) to describe the types of cutting edge approaches and the remaining open problems. Topics include distributional semantics (e.g., word vectors), frame semantics (e.g., semantic role labeling), model-theoretic semantics (e.g., semantic parsing), the role of context, grounding, neural networks, latent variables, and inference. The hope is that this unified presentation will clarify the landscape, and show that this is an exciting time for the machine learning community to engage in the problems in natural language understanding." />
    <meta name="part" content="1" />
    <meta name="date" content="Oct. 28, 2015" />
    <meta name="type" content="Tutorial" />
    <layout></layout>
</head>
<body>
    <switch region="video" dur="0:58:19" type="v">
        <video id="1001866" proto="rtmp" width="400" height="300" systemBitrate="416819" size="182348171" apptype="v" ext="mp4" type="video/mp4"  streamer="rtmp://hydro2.videolectures.net/vod" src="mp4:v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4"/>
        <video id="1001866" proto="m3u8" width="400" height="300" systemBitrate="416819" size="182348171" apptype="v" ext="mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL"  src="http://hydro2.videolectures.net/vod/_definst_/mp4:v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4/playlist.m3u8"/>
        <video id="1001866" proto="secure_download" width="400" height="300" systemBitrate="416819" size="182348171" apptype="v" ext="mp4" type="video/mp4"  src="http://videolectures.net/site/secure_dl/0345805d8bef53e4f3b95b58b3b9a4c2/5f811e37/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk/tag=1001866/icml2015_liang_language_understanding_01_400x300_h264.mp4"/>
        <video id="1001866" proto="http" width="400" height="300" systemBitrate="416819" size="182348171" apptype="v" ext="mp4" type="video/mp4"  src="http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4"/>

        <image src="http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/41/iff64giyif2niuz3bfwkkv6p7z7nko3g.jpg" width="400" height="300" type="screenshot"/>
        <image src="http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/41/ihgisuqj4vmqfygwzwuf7ifugpihurga.jpg" width="156" height="96" type="thumbnail"/>
    </switch>
</body>
</smil>
```

The JS part is located in [script-player.js](https://static.videolectures.net/r.1483388978/static/vl/js/script-player.js) and [smile.min.js](https://static.videolectures.net/r.1483388978/static/smileplayer/smile.min.js)

The following [python](/questions/tagged/python) script extract the JSON parameters from the source page, get the config, decode the config and parse xml to get the video url :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

#extract JSON config
r = requests.get("http://videolectures.net/icml2015_liang_language_understanding/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

extract = soup.findAll(text=re.compile("var\s+viipg\s*=\s*{"))[0]
extract = re.search(r".*cfg\s*:\s*({.*}),", extract)
jsObject = extract.group(1)

dict_str = lambda data : re.sub(r"([{,]\s*)([^\"':,]+)(\s*:)", r'\1"\2"\3', data).replace('\'', '"')

config = json.loads(dict_str(jsObject))

print(config)

#extract xml config
r = requests.get(f'http://videolectures.net/{config["slug"]}/video/{config["video"]}/page.map')

charList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~-_.,;:<>!?*+=\"'#$%&/\\()\n\t "
charLen = len(charList)

def updateSlug(a):
    d = 0
    for c in a:
        d += charList.find(c)
    return d if d >= 0 else 0

def parse(data, slug):
    h = []
    slug = updateSlug(slug);
    for idx, c in enumerate(data):
        f = charList.find(c)
        if f > -1:
            ni = (((f - slug - 6 * idx) % charLen) + charLen) % charLen
            h.append(charList[ni])
        else:
            h.append(c)
    return "".join(h)

#parse xml config
xmlConfig = parse(r.text[1:], config["slug"])
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlConfig, features="xml")

allVideos = [(t["proto"], t["src"]) for t in soup.find_all("video")]
print(allVideos)

httpVideo = [t for t in allVideos if t[0]=="http"][0]
print(httpVideo)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeVideoObfuscatedConf)

Output:

```
{'slug': 'icml2015_liang_language_understanding', 'type': 'Lecture', 'obj_id': 23694, 'video': 1, 'video_id': 23648, 'videos': [1, 2], 'chrome_colors': ['FFFFFF', 'F21F1F'], 'livepipe': '//videolectures.net', 'site_slug': 'vln', 'media_url': 'https://static.videolectures.net/r.1483388978/', 'sentry': '//161ef9a5c3a14af1848399909b890522@sentry.viidea.com/6'}
[('rtmp', 'mp4:v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4'), ('m3u8', 'http://hydro2.videolectures.net/vod/_definst_/mp4:v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4/playlist.m3u8'), ('secure_download', 'http://videolectures.net/site/secure_dl/14f30db64e8184a24b2bb4414dcfdc5d/5f8127f8/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk/tag=1001866/icml2015_liang_language_understanding_01_400x300_h264.mp4'), ('http', 'http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4')]
('http', 'http://hydro.ijs.si/v012/01/ae6se7y42if65i27glt3yfanffv5rvtk.mp4')
```